# Wordpress: Индивидуальный шаблон для записей в конкретной рубрике

Tags: wordpress

Нужно сделать так, чтобы для каждой записи в конкретной рубрике дизайн брался из файла, например `other.single.php`.

Как такое сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто создать [шаблон поста](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-page-templates-for-specific-post-types)

Опционально - использование [условного тега](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) `in_category`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете в single.php проверять id рубрики (in_category) и в зависимости от этого подключать нужный файл с разметкой/кодом. Например так:

```
  if (in_category('32')) { //ID категории
   include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-other.php');
  } else {
   include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-news.php');
  }
```

Comment: спасибо, а там верстка не смешается разве ?

подключать в файле с одним дизайном, файл с другим дизайном ..

Comment: либо там поставить условие, else если не в такой категории то подключать стандартную верстку для single.php ?
все понял, благодарю

Comment: если у вас стили разбиты на отдельные файлы (каждый css файл отвечает за свою страницу) то вы можете через functions.php (прописать условие подключения) подключать нужный вам файл-стиль

Answer (score -1):

Думаю правильней будет так
file single.php :

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if(file_exists('single/single-34.php')): ?>
       <?php get_template_part( 'single/single', get_cat_ID()); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
         <?php //Условие если нет "шаблона для категории" ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

//В папке single должен быть файл single-34.php

Comment: И что это даст? Только проверка файла, а если новость относиться к другой рубрике?